# numpy select values based on list of indices. Process batch at once

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

The general task seems rather straightforwad.
I have given two arrays:
Array `A of shape (5,20)` i.e. five lists of 100 values each. 
and another array `B of shape (5, 10)` containing the indices I want to select. [Thus array B contains values between 0 and 19]

A minimal example would be solved by

```
# saqmple initialization
def rnd():
    return np.random.choice(20, 10, replace=False)
A = np.random.random_sample((5, 20))
B = np.array([rnd(),  rnd(),  rnd(),  rnd(),  rnd()])

# solution
selected_values = [A[i,B[i]] for i in range(A.shape[0])]
```

as even even simpler example take

```
A = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
B = [[0,1],[1,2]]
out = [[4,5],[8,9]]
```

Is there a way to reshape, reformat or... to be then able to do this operation without a for loop? I.e. implicitly letting numpy realize that the second entry in B are indices corresponding to the second entry in A and so forth?

Comment: Use the linked one for array inputs. That's the only way to avoid looping (explicit or implicit).

Comment: can you elaborate on that?

Comment: only now saw the link to the other question. That helped, thanks :)